# Scaled prefab instantiating at weird angles and positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I have a scaled flamethrower prefab that I want to instantiate at the weapon point.  My other prefabs such as simple bullets and laser are instantiating fine with the same script but this prefab has weird locations and angles. How to fix this?

Here is the script that handles angle and instantiation:

```
public class FlameThrowerGun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject theFlame;

    bool isFiring = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        SetPlayerRotation();
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }

    }


    void SetPlayerRotation()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 45);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -45);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }


    void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject bullet_ = Instantiate(theFlame, transform.position, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -90f));
        Destroy(bullet_, 1.0f);

    }
}
```

The `* Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -90f)` is put in there to instantiate the flame at the correct angle.

I want to add that the flame prefab has been scaled to `y=2` to get the desired size, and rather than instantiating at the edge of the prefab, its instantiated at the centre thats why I feel it has this weird position.

Here it is when fired straight and fired at an angle, none of them are at the player weapon position:

https://gfycat.com/EntireGraciousBlueandgoldmackaw

Comment: I suppose it is because of sprite pivot point. I think that your character sprite and flame sprite have both centered pivot point. So that your flame sprite position (its center) sets to character sprite position (also center).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The pivot point of your bullet object needs to be altered

Right now the pivot point of your bullet is in the center, so when it gets spawned and placed by your code, the pivot (aka the center) ends up *right where you asked it to.* The problem is, you don't want it there.

So right now your prefab looks something like this:

[image: Ring in the center]

See the ring in the center? Drag that over to the left:

[image: Fixed!]

Put it right at the spot that it should overlap with the gun barrel.

<sub>And ignore my crappy attempt at duplicating your flame via screen grab</sub>

You'll probably have to add an offset if the positioning is from your character's sprite's pivot, or use an empty game object that sits at the gun barrel as well, but the core principle here is that because the pivots are centered, they're being aligned center-to-center when you call `Instantiate`

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that pivot change was my problem. I would like to add that since I am using 2D sprites for my flamethrower, I was not able to change the pivot location as suggested by you in the Unity editor. I could only change the pivot positions in the sprite editor when importing the sprites. :)

Comment: @StuckInPhD Yeah, different systems work a different way, and I wasn't sure what you were using, but I could make a mockup using a uGUI element in a few minutes.